# What kind of chilis have purple, red and yellow fruit?

Tags: identification, chili

My grandmother planted these chilis (see pic) last year, however she was expecting a different plant. I really liked the look of them, they are like flowers, so colorful.
I'd like to know the breed, can anyone help me out?

[image]

Comment: they're not worth buying in my opinion as they don't produce much

Comment: Can you specify? They are small but I thought that there were plenty on the plants :) BR

Comment: look carefully at the plants, and they look like that near the end of the growing season only. I tried the medusa last year, and didn't produce anything like I was expecting, and other ones didn't produce at all. I'm speaking from personal experience if you're wanting to grow food.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i got myself more seeds from another breed so that I can compare :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular form of chilli is usually produced for ornamental purposes only,as a decorative but short lived houseplant, and is generally known as 'ornamental chilli plant'. The chillies are edible, but very hot and said to be without much flavour; there are many other varieties grown purely for culinary use.

If you google ornamental chilli you should find packets of seeds by different producers, all with different names and slightly different colours and shape of fruit. Some general information here http://puffycarrot.com/grow-care-ornamental-pepper-plant/

UPDATE: The seed of a very similar variety is listed and available on Ebay in the UK as 'ornamental chili pepper' but not sure they'll ship to where you are - best to check local suppliers https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/50pcs-Garden-Ornamental-Pepper-Seed-Organic-Chilli-Pepper-Seeds-Pot-Culture-UK-/141994665115?redirect=mobile

Comment: I saw it a shop by the name “Thai Silk Chilli”. Example: https://www.oasishorticulture.com.au/products/344

Comment: There are many varieties of such chilies, but contrary to Bamboo, not all are hot. If you keep as "house flower" it could be without flavour, but if you get more sun and less water you may get better flavours. But like many chilies, the outcome could be random. -- If you want edible chili peppers, you should select the variety you like and look for such seeds, do no look for species name or form of fruit (or colour).

Comment: @Daria I never found that link at all via Google, well done... I note that one is available in Australia, but it seems  to be sold as a culinary variety rather than being sold as an ornamental chili houseplant, possibly because it can be grown outdoors even in winter.  All very confusing because it seems any names for the  ornamental plants seem to be made up by whatever seed company is selling them... If I google 'thai silk chili', it  does not show me that particular plant in your link; seems a bit hit and miss if what you actually want is the multi coloured more decorative type...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not expecting such fast and accurate answers :)
I did not clarify that I do have the seeds (and fruit) of this chili from last year, they are growing right now. However I wanted to know what I am actually growing, so nonetheless thanks a lot for the shop links!
The chilis were outside the whole summer. They are mildly hot, one fruit (quite small, ~1cm) is enough to spice up two food portions. I really like them, however I am not a connaisseur. BR @Bamboo: fyi: I cannot upvote yet.

Comment: @earthling - be aware, if your chili plants were outside last year, and you collected seed from them, what grows this year may not be the same as the plants you previously had - they do not necessarily come true from seed when open pollinated (not isolated in a closed environment). As for the peppers themselves, I'm not a connoisseur either, I loathe hot spicy food and avoid chili like the plague, sticking instead with other, not so hot spices like ginger!

Comment: haha :D If its fatty und spicy, I'll love it :) Thanks for the heads up!